# Tire :include_in_all => false but fields are still included in _all

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using tire for implementing search for a rails app.
The app is backed by CouchDB & couchrest_model gem, which implements ActiveModel.

From the readme it would seen that there's an option :include_in_all it's not explained as to it's behaviour but I'd presume the index would not be included when querying _all

Given the following mapping

```
mapping do
  indexes :id,                :index    => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false
  indexes :title,             :analyzer => 'snowball', :boost => 100
  indexes :question_content,  :analyzer => 'snowball'
  indexes :skill_id,          :index    => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false
  indexes :topic_id,          :index    => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false
  indexes :archived,          :type     => 'boolean', :include_in_all => false
  indexes :created_at,        :type     => 'date', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false
  indexes :published_at,      :type     => 'date', :index => 'not_analyzed', :include_in_all => false
end
```

I'd expect ES to only search indexes for `title` and `question_content` when not specifying a default_field in a query.

Am I miss understanding or is this a bug?

//edit

deleting the index and re-creating it recognises the include_in_all options i've set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the index and re-creating it recognises the include_in_all options i've set.